# QTP 10 does not generate script when recording a web application

Tags: testing, automation

I am using qtp 10 and version 9 of internet explorer. Whenever i try to record my application it does not generate the code except for moving or resizing the window etc. I tried to convert it to IE 8 from developer tools option and recorded but no results achieved yet. Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

You need to run QTP using by admin, 
i.e if you run qtp as